# Python File reader convert invalid literal

Tags: python

I have been trying to make python code that reads a text file makes it a variable and sends it using i2c. Heres the code:

```
import serial
import smbus
import time
import sys

from time import sleep



# for RPI version 1, use "bus = smbus.SMBus(0)"
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

# This is the address we setup in the Arduino Program
address = 0x04

loopvar = 1

while loopvar == 1:
    text_file = open("./PB_Vision/command.txt", "r")
    print text_file.read()
    visioncommando = text_file.read()
    print visioncommando

    def writeNumber(value):
        bus.write_byte(address, value)
        bus.write_byte_data(address, 0, value)
        return -1

    var = int(visioncommando)
    writeNumber(var)
    print ("RPI: Hi Arduino, I sent you")
    print (var)

    text_file.close()
```

when I run this, I get this as output;

```
110

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testai.py", line 29, in <module>
  var = int(visioncommando)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

any suggestion, fixes?

anyways thanks in advance.

Thanks your suggestions worked, one step closer  to an working project.

Comment: what value did you get from visioncommando and what type is it

Comment: 110 and it should be a string if you'd use text_file.read but now I am doubting that

Comment: It's an empty string as stated by the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your `command.txt` file contains:

```
110
```

Then the following code is wrong:

```
while loopvar == 1:
    text_file = open("./PB_Vision/command.txt", "r")
    print text_file.read()
    visioncommando = text_file.read()
    print visioncommando
```

Your 2nd `text_file.read()` call will result in `""` (*en empty string*) because you've already exhausted the contents of the open file object.

You could do something liket his instead:

```
while loopvar == 1:
    text_file = open("./PB_Vision/command.txt", "r")
    visioncommando = text_file.read()
    print visioncommando
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this:

```
print text_file.read()
```

and it will work.
Iterators can only be used once...

Comment: I dont know,  testing it now :)

Answer (score 0):

You read the file in the wrong way, python convert `110` to `int` but it find an empty string `''` after that. So I would suggest to add a condition before `int()` command and `str.isdigit()` is a good candidate.